# Plot two lists with different color with stem

Tags: python, matlab, list, matplotlib, machine-learning

I plot a list (`s_n_hat`) with the Matlba-like `stem()`, like this:

```
markerline, stemlines, _ = plt.stem(s_n_hat, '-.')
plt.setp(markerline, 'markerfacecolor', 'b')
plt.setp(baseline, 'color','r', 'linewidth', 2)
plt.show()
```

In my real application I want to plot the hits with blue and the misses with red, how should I do that? So, some elements should be colored blue and some red.

Assuming that my vector has its first part with hits and its second one with misses, I tried to do this:

```
s_n_hat = [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
markerline1, stemlines, _ = plt.stem(s_n_hat[0:5], '-.')
plt.setp(markerline1, 'markerfacecolor', 'b')
markerline2, stemlines, _ = plt.stem(s_n_hat[6:9], '-.')
plt.setp(markerline2, 'markerfacecolor', 'r')
plt.setp(baseline, 'color','r', 'linewidth', 2)
plt.show()
```

and I would expect the first elements to be blue and all the others red, but they seem to be mixed:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "random"? Have a blue dot and a red dot for the same x? That they overlap?

Comment: @lbellomo mixed, updated with a picture!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

> If no * x * values are provided, the default is (0, 1, ..., len (y) -1)

Then you need to pass an x, but the points overlap. Something like:

```
s_n_hat = [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
x1 = list(range(0, 5))
x2 = list(range(5, 8))
markerline1, stemlines, _ = plt.stem(x1, s_n_hat[0:5], '-.')
plt.setp(markerline1, 'markerfacecolor', 'b')
markerline2, stemlines, _ = plt.stem(x2, s_n_hat[6:9], '-.')
plt.setp(markerline2, 'markerfacecolor', 'r')
plt.show()
```

[image]